# HEDGING WITH A PUT OPTION

Tags: options, hedging, put

[image]

In the following example, for 3rd question and 4th question why do we have to add (Stock price in three months - Current stock price) to put option profit?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A *hedged stock position* means that you own the stock *and* an option to reduce the risk. For owning the stock, you pay $S_0$ but receive $S_T$ in 3 months. Similarly, your option costs $1.50$ but will give you $\max\{X-S_T,0\}$.